# how can I put the data retrieved in a string array

Tags: android

I am working on an app, which takes data from the user, stores the data in the database. The data is retrieved using cursor, and should be put in a string array. I am successful till the retrieving part, but how can I put the data in a string array? and is using string array the right approach here?, I mean data is being added continuously and the string array size is fixed. Not sure what to do here, please help.

Comment: Why do you think you need an array ? what are you going to do with it?

Comment: Please put your code upto retrieving the data from database.

Comment: @Komitsev Anatoly , with the String array I was trying to further customise my expandable list view, by storing the data in a string array, I'd be able to provide the swap list item functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Okay found a solution here http://www.anddev.org/working%5Fwith%5Fthe%5Fsqlite-database%5F-%5Fcursors-t319.html
, using ArrayList would help here.

Answer (score 0):

@sam You got to use `ArrayList<String>` for ur requirements.u can add ur retrieved data into `ArrayList`by this method:

```
arrayList.add(<ur retrieved string>);
```